# Return true/false along with model data

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm attempting to return a true or false (in JSON) along with my model data. Code builds and runs fine but I only get a return on my model data.

**What I've tried from reading other answers:**

```
public IQueryable<Book> GetBooks()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return db.Books;
 }
```

As you can probably easily see, I don't have the greatest idea of what I'm doing, but through the infinite wisom of this community I hope to learn another feat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a view model and returned that from the controller

```
public class BooksVm 
{
     public IQueryable<Book> Books { get; set; }
     public bool BooleanValue { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBooks()
{
   var booksVm = new BooksVm() { Books = db.Books, BooleanValue = true };
   return Ok(booksVm);
}
```

Comment: `Ok(booksVm)` is return an error of `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<BookService.ViewModels.BooksVm>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<BookService.Models.Book>'`

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy: Change the return type of your GetBooks to IHttpActionResult as per Mihail's instructions.

Comment: @JoakimSkoog Ah I missed that part, thank you for pointing it out.